# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser inside Asp.net WebForm DocumentCompleted not fired

Tags: asp.net, browser, webbrowser-control

Yeah some people would say "Are you crazy using winforms controls inside asp forms"... and I think they are right. But I would say.. "I'm not the only one!!, take a look"

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b7cce396-e2b3-42d7-9571-cdc4eb38f3c1/build-a-selfcaching-asp.aspx

So...

Doing some kind of stuff like the previous link. I did the following:

using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace XXXX.aspx.Print
{
    public partial class Drucker : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Threading();
    }

    private void Threading()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GoAhead));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        mre.WaitOne();
        t.Abort();
    }

    private void GoAhead()
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();

        webBrowser.Navigate(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(0);
            TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - time;
            if (elapsedTime.Seconds >= 13)
            {
                mre.Set();
            }
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }

    void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != webBrowser.Url.AbsolutePath) return;

        webBrowser.Print();
    }
}
```

}

Now...

the DocumentCompleted event is not fired (neither ProgressChanged) and I've tried  the next:

1. Add the library MsHtml.dll to my project and place the file into my lib folder... I did it... No changes.
2. Try to handle the state of the WebBrowser.ReadyState... I did it... No changes (Actually after receive the WebBrowserReadyState.Complete I tried to print the document with 
   webBrowser.Print(); but I receive a weird IE pop up telling me: "'dialogArguments.__IE_PrintType' is Null or a not an object'"... ok so doing some research I got: a microsoft topic about dcomcnfg and some com security settings
   I did it... No changes.
   ...

By the way I´m working in 64bits, Win7...
So before I format the whole computer...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowser is never inplace-activated by its ActiveX container, which you don't have. Try put it on a form first.

By the way, you know you are [in the unsupported territory when you use WinInet, the network layer of webbrowser control, in a Windows Service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238425), right?

Comment: You are right...! The uncertain terrain of wins in iis is not recommended.